# Scheduled task for C++ EXE not working

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks

I've bought a VPS, but it has been restarting on occasion. The server is meant to be running my game server 24/7, but when it restarts obviously the game goes down too.

I'm trying to setup a scheduled task to run the C++ game server EXE on start up, but it isn't working. I've already set a scheduled task to run WAMP so I know that the scheduled tasks actually work, but for the C++ EXE it just isn't.

I've even compiled a very simple program that just waits for user input before closing, and set this as a scheduled task. When I restart the server, this program doesn't even run.

Any ideas? Is this a problem specific to running an executable like this?

It's also strange, on the scheduled task manager it says the program is running, but no console is on screen...

OS: Windows Server 2003

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: @Matthew, do you enable the task?

Comment: @sharptooth Well if the basic input program ran, it would still be waiting for input until I entered something.

Comment: @Eric I assume that's automatic, since for WAMP I didn't need to? Where do I "enable" the tasks?

Comment: @Matthew All Programs->Accessories->System Tools->Scheduled Tasks, right click your scheduled task, ->Properties->Enabled(..)

Comment: @Eric They are enabled. I noticed something though, it says the program is running but there is no console displayed?

Comment: @Matthew, which Windows are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Windows Server 2003, check out [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/b15962d6-92dd-48eb-971c-73d5d7c0be97) to *allow services to interact with desktop*.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful to know. I think there's an additional problem in that I'm not using this functionality as it's meant to be used. I'll have to make some changes to get it to work in this manner, and then hopefully there will be no more problems.